# If $d(x,A)=0\forall x\in X$ for some subset $A$ of $X$, does it follow that $A$ is dense?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $d(x,A)=0 \:\:\forall x\in X$ for some subset $A$ of $X$ then $A$ is dense in $X$, right?

Once I did one problem which says $d(x,A)=0\Leftrightarrow x\in \bar{A}$ so by the condition here we get $\bar{A}=X$.

Other options were

$2$. $A$ is closed

$3$. $A=X$

$4$. $A$ is compact

A counterexample for $2, 3$ and $4$ is $A=\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}=X$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if all points of $X$ have distance $0$ to $A$ then $A$ is dense, because then all points are in the closure of $A$.

Comment: You mean $X$ and $A$ can not be disjoint?

Comment: @BabakS. $A$ is a subset of $X$, so I don't see what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Look at $B(x,\epsilon)$. Since $d(x,A)=0 \forall x \in X$, $\exists a \in A$ such that $a\in B(x,\epsilon)$. Since these open balls form a base of the topology of $X$, every open set $U \in X$ contains an element of $A$. Hence $A$ is dense in $X$.